# Using a different framework for the front-end with Magento

Tags: magento, reactjs

We have our website in magento and as it appears, Front-end is tightly coupled with back-end in magento apps.

We would slowly like to move towards using react js for the front end library and have the front-end completely decoupled from the back-end.

Also, we have a REST api over magento that we would like to call from React. However, as I see, a lot of stuff seems to be going on behind the scene in terms of sessions. (at least the session initialization part)

My question is, how would the session initialization part comes into the picture if I use react as the front end library and magento for back-end.

What I need to know is how can I have my sessions handled properly if I move away from magento temlplating to react? I read that we could have mage.php and call the function directly but I am not sure if that is really what I will need to know.

Could I have some pointers on this please?A slightest direction would help as I feel lost right now. (Note: I do not know much about Magento or PHP)